# How to display constraint errors from form in JSON using Flask-SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Right now, my project accepts user information from a form and returns the information as a POST request in JSON. The created user is also saved into the database. That is exactly what I want to do, however if the user inputs information that doesn't satisfy its constraint, I would like the end route to list JSON showing the errors. For example:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "color": [
      "Invalid value, must be one of: red, blue, yellow"
    ],
    "email": [
      "This field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

I thought you could create something in the model class to handle these errors when constraints aren't satisfied. However, I can't find anything about this in the Flask-SQL Alchemy documentation or searching around online. Right now if the user types in the wrong input type (i.e. letters in the year field), a sqlalchemy.exc.DataError is shown along with bunch of tracebacks. This also occurs if a user's input is over the field's character limit. Also, when an input field is skipped, it just shows "" in the field in the created JSON rather than stating "This field is required." How would I create the above JSON to show these errors? My code is below

"""app.py"""

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, session, request, jsonify
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from werkzeug.exceptions import Unauthorized

from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgres:///database_example"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "shhhhh"
app.config['DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS'] = False

connect_db(app)
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)


@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    """Show homepage."""
    return redirect("/api")

@app.route("/api", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def json_api():
    """JSON API Endpoint"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User(
            name = request.form["name"], 
            year = request.form["birth_year"],
            email = request.form["email"],
            color = request.form["color"],
        )
        
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        user_dict = user.to_dict()
        return jsonify(user_dict)
        # return jsonify(user_dict)

    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

######################## """ models.py """##########################

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


class User(db.Model):
    """User."""

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Float(4), nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    def to_dict(self):
        """Serialize user to a dict of user info."""

        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "name": self.name,
            "email": self.email,
            "year": self.year,
            "color": self.color,
        }


def connect_db(app):
    """Connect to database."""

    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
```

######################### """ index.html """ ##########################

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form" method="POST">
  <div>Name: <input id="name" name="name"> <b id="name-err"></b> </div>
  <div>Birth Year: <input id="year" name="birth_year"> <b id="year-err"></b> </div>
  <div>Email: <input id="email" name="email"> <b id="email-err"></b> </div>
  <div>Color: <input id="color" name="color"> <b id="color-err"></b> </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Making a comment as this doesn't specifically answer your question, but using the [HTML built-in form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) could cover a significant amount of your requirements. Check out [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a look at this libraries:

- https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
- https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Marshmallow will handle user input validation using object.
It is very similar to SQL Alchemy models.

Mixing user input and DB model may create more complexity.
You may keep them separated.

You can create validation object for your request like bellow:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True


@app.errorhandler(422)
@app.errorhandler(400)
def handle_error(err):
    """Return validation errors as JSON"""
    headers = err.data.get("headers", None)
    messages = err.data.get("messages", ["Invalid request."])
    if headers:
        return jsonify({"errors": messages}), err.code, headers
    else:
        return jsonify({"errors": messages}), err.code


class UserSchema(Schema):
    """This class handle user input and validation"""
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    year = fields.Int(required=True, strict=True,
                      validate=validate.Range(min=1900, max=2100))
    email = fields.Email(required=True)
    color = fields.String(required=True, validate=validate.OneOf([
        "red",
        "blue",
        "yellow",
    ]))


@dataclass
class User:
    """This class can be replaced by sql alchemy or whatever
    business logic concerned object"""
    name: str
    year: int
    email: str
    color: str


@app.route("/api", methods=["POST"])
@use_args(UserSchema(), location="json")
def json_api(args):
    # Create user object
    user = User(**args)

    # Process it
    ...

    # Render response
    return jsonify(asdict(user))
```

Using following curl request to test it:

```sh
set -x
curl -X POST localhost:5000/api \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{}'

curl -X POST localhost:5000/api \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"color": "green", "foobar": 42}'

curl -X POST localhost:5000/api \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"color": "red", "name": "me", "year": 1950, "email": "me@web.com"}'
```

You got the following results:

```
+ curl -X POST localhost:5000/api --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{}'
{
  "errors": {
    "json": {
      "color": [
        "Missing data for required field."
      ], 
      "email": [
        "Missing data for required field."
      ], 
      "name": [
        "Missing data for required field."
      ], 
      "year": [
        "Missing data for required field."
      ]
    }
  }
}
+ curl -X POST localhost:5000/api --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"color": "green", "foobar": 42}'
{
  "errors": {
    "json": {
      "color": [
        "Must be one of: red, blue, yellow."
      ], 
      "email": [
        "Missing data for required field."
      ], 
      "foobar": [
        "Unknown field."
      ], 
      "name": [
        "Missing data for required field."
      ], 
      "year": [
        "Missing data for required field."
      ]
    }
  }
}
+ curl -X POST localhost:5000/api --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"color": "red", "name": "me", "year": 1950, "email": "me@web.com"}'
{
  "color": "red", 
  "email": "me@web.com", 
  "name": "me", 
  "year": 1950
}
```